# Writing a constructor for a poker game in Java

Tags: java, arrays, poker

there is already a class called Card.java with 52 cards. And in the Deck.java i have to write a constructor to initialize the 52 cards in a row with suite and value. i wrote the following code but it failed the public test..Can anybody help me out?

```
public class Deck {
    private Card[] cards;
    private final int DECK_SIZE=52;

    public Deck(){
        this.cards=new Card[DECK_SIZE];
        int index = 0;
        for (int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++) {
            for (int value = 1; value <= 13; value++) {
                this.cards[index] = new Card (suit, value);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
    public Deck(Deck other) {
        this.cards= new Card[DECK_SIZE];
        for(int i=1;i<=DECK_SIZE;i++){
            this.cards[i]= other.cards[i];
}
```

Comment: Public test? Is there an error message?

Comment: It looks good, from far. What does "failed the public test" mean?

Comment: Are you assured that for the second constructor, the given deck's size is the same as yours?

Comment: Looks good to me.  What does your test look like, and are you sure the Card class is not at fault somehow?

Comment: Seems that it's homework, no? and BTW, this error can be easily found if you run your application at least 1 time and try to actually **read** exception that was thrown, because of this **-1** from me.

Answer (score 1):

In your second constructor you iterating from `1` to `DECK_SIZE` (`1..52`), but you shoud iterate starting from `0`:

```
    for(int i=0; i<DECK_SIZE;i++){
        this.cards[i]= other.cards[i];
    }
```

Your code should throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @javaLearner: All java arrays are starting at index `0`. You can find more info here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop,

```
for(int i=1;i<=DECK_SIZE;i++){
```

is incorrect, it should read

```
for(int i=0;i <DECK_SIZE;i++){
```

An array of size 52 only has indexes from 0 to 51.

Comment: its not actually..since i intialize to 1, its gonna go from 1 to 52.

Comment: All arrays start at 0, and go to index array.length - 1 inclusive. The array 'does not care' whether you init i to 1 or not, it just accepts indexes 0..51 and your last iteration has index == 52.

Answer (score 0):

The Java tutorials have a good example of a way to create a deck using Enum values:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html

The conventional way of doing arrays in java is to `for (int i = 0; i < XXX; i++)`. You should change your Suit loop then to be `<4` not `<=3`, and your Deck look in the second constructor to be `for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)`. Arrays of length n start at index 0 and finish at index n-1.

Can a deck have less than 52 cards? In that case, your second constructor might throw an exception of some kind; as it is it will give an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.